# How to pass environment variables to an unstarted container in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I created a Fargate task in ECS that waits for Container Ordering to start up Container A (containing MySQL) before starting up Container B (containing batch), and created a system to start it up using the ECS Run Task API.

In this case, when I try to pass environment variables to the containers in the task using containerOverrides, I can pass the environment variables to container A, but I get an error `Override for container named container B is not a container in the TaskDefinition.`  for container B, and cannot pass the environment variables.

Is it possible to pass value to a container that is waiting to be activated by Container Ordering using containerOverrides?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think we block passing variables based on startup order. Stupid question I know but can you make sure the name of container B is correct? The error message seems to be saying it can't find the container. Weird.

Comment: Ah...I was being silly.
The revision of the task definition specified in RunTask was old, so the correct container name was not included in the parameter and an error occurred.
After correcting this point, it can now be executed normally.
Thanks for pointing it out.